# Event is not defined onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

well I have this code in PHP and send this string "ABARFL31112421M900" in the echo:

```
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON  onClick="openDialog(<?php echo $_pagi_resultSubLider ->fields['id'];?>)"   VALUE="Ver Estructura"></TD>
```

And after I have this event in the

```
 function openDialog($Id_var)    {
    $('<div/>').dialog({
        modal: true, 
  show: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 500
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 500
  },

 open: function ()
        {

        if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
            $(this).load('Ver_Estructura.php?id_ver=' + $Id_var);
            }
        },         
        height: 580,
       width:580,
        title:"Estructura"
    });
}
```

But doesn't work, when I view consolejavascript this is the return:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ABARFL31112421M900 is not defined

Comment: This question was caused by a simple **typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the function parameter in quotes since it is a string

`openDialog(<?php echo $_pagi_resultSubLider ->fields['id'];?>)`

Should be

`openDialog('<?php echo $_pagi_resultSubLider ->fields['id'];?>')`